# How to find the convergence region of this power series

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Note:** The following questions are from the second question of the [2011 Chinese Graduate Entrance Examination Mathematics](https://max.book118.com/html/2018/0905/8044053134001122.shtm) (first set):

Suppose the number sequence $\left\{a_{n}\right\}$ decreases monotonically, $ \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n}=0$, and series $\quad S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}(n=1,2 \cdots \cdots)$ has no boundaries (divergence), what is the region of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}(x-1)^{n} $.

At present I know that because the sequence $\left\{a_{n}\right\}$ is a decreasing sequence and greater than $0$, the alternating series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}(-1)^{n} $ converges.

Comment: Initially, I upvoted because this is a really interesting question.  Then, I reversed it because the OP hasn't shown any work.  To OP: please edit your posting to indicate what you have tried and what roadblock(s) you have encountered.  Please also include **context**: is this from a contest, book, or class.  If not from contest, please briefly describe the theorems or pertinent prior problems that lead up to this problem.

Comment: To everyone else: I am very interested in this question, but am clueless about it.  In the absence of the OP editing his posting, please consider giving hints, guides, online references pertinent to the question.

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you for your reply. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that if $\;|x-1|<1\iff 0<x<2\;$, then the geometric series $\;\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(x-1)^n\;$ converges, and since $\;a_n\to 0\;$ monotonically (and is thus bounded), then  our series converges by

[Abel's Test.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test)

Thus, the convergence radius is at least $\;R=1\;$ ...Can you see why the right point $\;x=2\;$ is **not** contained in the convergence interval? Thus, the convergence radius is **exactly** $\;1\;$ .

Comment: I want to know how you got $A=\varlimsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_{n}}=1$, so that the convergence radius of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}(x-1)^{n} $ is R=1.

Comment: @PleasecorrectGrammarMistakes I didn't have to use the Cauchy-Hadamard formula, just to pay attention to the given data and use Abel's Theorem ...

Answer (score 2):

Hints : It's clearly, $ 0 \le x \lt 2 $ , just use the Dirichlet's test, partial sum of the series $\sum (x-1)^n $ is bounded on $ 0 \le x \lt 2 $.